# Return an array of multiple 2 using created method

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

I'm a new learner of Ruby. I'm doing an exercise which a method will take the integers in an array, multiply by 2, then return them in a new array.

Here is my code:

```
array = [1,2,3]

def maps(x)
  x.map { |int| int*2 }
end

p maps([array])
```

I get the result:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Why is that? And how should I rewrite the code so that it will return [2,4,6]?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your argument to maps method is `[[1,2,3]]`, an array with a single element which is an array. Ruby has a peculiar property that you can multiply an array and integer and get an array with all elements duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

Should be just...

```
p maps(array)
```

The way it's implemented, you actually pass an array of arrays into `maps`:

```
p maps([[1,2,3]])
```

Therefore mapping function - `{ |int| int*2 }` - is actually invoked just once, and its argument is `[1,2,3]` array. What you see is result of `*` operator applied to [Array * Int combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-2A):

> **ary * int** → *new_ary*
>
> **ary * str** → *new_string*
>
> **Repetition.** With a String argument, equivalent to `ary.join(str)`.
> Otherwise, returns a new array built by concatenating the `int` copies
> of self.
>
> [ 1, 2, 3 ] * 3    #=> [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 ]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So what I did was multiplied the original array by 2, that's why I get [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]].

Comment: Yes. Technically it was called a repetition, not multiplication though. :)